# SSL request fails from Soap UI, works with fiddler proxy

Tags: java, ssl, https, soapui, soap-client

HTTPŞ request to SOAP web service doesn't work from SOAP UI directly, but when I put fiddler proxy, it works, it also works with WcfTestClient from Visual studio.

I tried:

1.using SOAP UI 5.0.0 and 5.2.0.

2.Putting these switches:

```
-Djavax.net.debug=all
-Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true
-Dsun.security.ssl.allowLegacyHelloMessages=true
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1 (because server doesn't support SSL, only TLS)
```

3.Adding CA certficate and server SSL cert to (because SSL cert is signed with "homemade CA certficate")

- \jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\security\cacerts
- importing them trough java control panel.

Here is the exception I get:

```
Mon Jul 06 13:42:57 CEST 2015:ERROR:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flush(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.flush(LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.java:95)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.flush(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:102)
    at org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity.writeTo(ByteArrayEntity.java:69)
    at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:96)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:120)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:263)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.sendRequestEntity(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:227)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:255)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpClientSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:633)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:454)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$Helper.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:233)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:323)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.submitRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:290)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:220)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:119)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
   Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    ... 31 more
```

Comment: Editing the JRE for adding a self-signed certificate is bad style. Better create a TrustManager-instance that trusts exact this one self-signed certificate.

Comment: What version of TLS server is running ??

Comment: @PranavManiar Server supports TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, TLS 1.2, Here is a sample from fiddler which works - SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.
Version: 3.1 (TLS/1.0)

Comment: Hmm.. This seems good.. Not sure what is going wrong.. One thing you can try is to create a truststore with certificate of homemade CA and Server Certificate and use that truststore inside SOAP UI.. But not sure how much it will help ..

Comment: @PranavManiar I just tried with Server cert issued by real CA authority, same thing and AFAIK soap ui should trust that Server cert without importing because real CA-as are already imported, right? Now I think it isn't related to certificate..

Comment: Yups.. does not seem to be related to certificate now..  I m sure when u find the real issue it would be something interesting to know.. post it when it finally works for you !

Comment: @PranavManiar See the answer below :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem was due to [Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication).
We had multiple SSL certs for different FQDN-s running on same IP:port, so server is forced to use SNI, which is apparently [supported from java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/enhancements-7.html).

One more thing I didn't know is that SOAP UI has jre packed with it in installation folder, and it's version reports 1.7u55 for SOAP UI 5.2.0, but user-agent in http requests in fiddler reports Java 1.5.

As soon as we removed other SSL certs it worked from SOAP UI, that was just to prove point - that this was due to SNI. In production we have to go with SNI and make sure our clients support it.

Here is [thread about SOAP UI SNI](http://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-NG/When-will-SoapUI-support-SNI/td-p/96005) but suggestions in thread don't work, so I assume that there is no support for SNI in SOAP UI (Obviusly since the http client reports user agent: Java 1.5)

Comment: The problem likely isn't SNI itself, but instead that the server is misconfigured to send an unrecognized_name alert if the client-provided name isn't recognized, sending that alert against the advice of standards. You can check for this using the SSLLabs.com server test; also see the "SNI Hack" section of http://www.telerik.com/blogs/what-s-new-in-fiddler-4-5-1

Comment: @EricLaw It's not, I checked. It's an IIS server so there is not much you can misconfigure from UI. Anyway it worked with Spring soap templates (custom client in Java 1.7).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that reply: the IIS Server does have a configuration UI into which you set the expected hostname. The callstack above would come if an unexpected record were received, not if the server sent the wrong certificate (name mismatch).

Comment: @EricLaw I Was in hurry so I thought you meant checkbox Require server name indication :) Hostnames were correct and I inspected responses to make sure I didn't get unrecognized_name as I was aware of this, at least it was an interesting adventure.

Comment: SoapUI, as of 5.2.1, uses Apache HttpClient 4.1.1.  Support for SNI was not introduced until HttpClient 4.3.2, as described in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1119